MYSQL is very slow when combing LIKE with EQUALS or IN, but not other OR operators
SELECT
    products.*,
    products_description.* 
FROM
    products
    LEFT JOIN products_description ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id
    LEFT JOIN products_rooms ON products_rooms.products_id = products.products_id 
WHERE
    products_status = 1 
    AND ( products_name LIKE '%kitchen%' OR products_rooms.room_id = 5 ) 
GROUP BY
    products.products_id

In this query if I remove either the products_name LIKE '%kitchen%' or products_rooms.room_id = 5 the query is virtually instant. However if I combine them with the "OR" the query takes 8 seconds (reference table is about 7000 records).
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

What is the size of the cursor without extra condition, please? SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE products_status = 1? Is it about 7000?

MySQL hs trouble using indexes when you have OR conditions. Split this into two queries that you merge with UNION.

@DmitryBychenko about 3000

You have 3 tables, one of them has 7000, it's unclear how many records are there in the other two and how many tuples there will be in the end.
Your claim is that the two criteria in ( products_name LIKE '%kitchen%' OR products_rooms.room_id = 5 ) are slow together, whereas they are instant otherwise.
This strongly suggests that you have some indexes that quicken the query if one of them is in use, but there are still many records and checking the second criteria will take too long.
So, you will need to consider the creation of indexes upon (product_name, room_id) or the other way around, if these two fields are in the same table. If not, then you will need to consider restructuring your tables in order to better cope with this kind of search.

Thanks Lajos. products is 6,500 records, products_descriptions 6,400 records. and products_rooms 3685 records. products_rooms seems to be the one causing the problems, This has an an auto_increment primary index of room_index. which obviously I can't search. It seems odd to be that searching these separately the query is run in under 1s, but over 8s if combined. I can't help but think that I must have created a massive query, but I can't see how I have done.

@Clive what is the query plan?
